# IP route not on default gateway

Tags: networking, routing, ip, route

I am trying to setup a network that is only accessible if you go through the '10.222.3.1' switch. It is a test environment that we do not want interfering with our production environment. The trouble I'm having is the core switch '10.222.3.254' (which is the default gateway) and DHCP server is not controlled by my team. I'd use an access control list, but we want everyone who goes through '10.222.3.1' (whom have dynamic IPs) to be able to access this network.

I can ping the '192.168.x.x' network from the switches but when trying to access it from a PC, I get sent to the default gateway. Changing my default gateway to '10.222.3.0' allows me to access this. Any ideas on how to get this working?

[image]

10.222.3.0 - HP Procurve 3500
10.222.3.1 - HP Procurve 2610
10.222.3.2 - Cisco 2960
10.222.3.254 - Cisco 3850

Comment: The users default gateway is going to be their first hop, you would need to get the team that manages that device to announce the route for you or modify each client workstation and set a static route to the network you want them to get to.

Answer (score 0):

Make the team to add the route in Cisco.

```
ip route 192.168.x.x 255.255.0.0 10.222.3.1
```

reference: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/iproute/command/reference/fiprrp_r/1rfindp1.html#wp1054112